# Converting scikit-learn ML Models into C language for Microcontrollers

Tags: python, c, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am evaluating various ML models using **scikit-learn** package. I am validating **Logistic Regression, SVM and Random Forest Classifier** which is avaialble on sci-kit learn. In the first step, I am working on these using Python.

I would like to deploy these classifier algorithms and the trained ML model into a microcontroller. **I would need to convert my ML algorithm in scikit-learn from Python to C or C++ and then flash the code into my MCU.**

I looked over the internet and I could not find any librabries of scikit-learn packages written in C/C++ language.

If it is not directly possible to migrate with scikit-learn, are there any ML Classifier libraries (Logistic Regression, SVM, Random Forest Classifier) written in C language?

Comment: Please **re-read** [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO. Such questions should be posted at [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: emlearn allows you to generate C code from such scikit-learn models, designed for microcontrollers. https://github.com/emlearn/emlearn

Answer (score 8):

What you're looking for is an edge ML solution. <s>I'm not aware of any way to directly on indirectly deploy a `scikit-learn` model on a microcontroller, but</s> The [sklearn-porter project](https://github.com/nok/sklearn-porter), [micromlgen](https://github.com/eloquentarduino/micromlgen) or [emlearn](https://github.com/emlearn/emlearn) might be just what you're looking for. There's also plenty of other interesting work going on. One thing you definitely should have a look at is [Tensorflow Lite for Microcontrollers](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/microcontrollers). Other options include Microsoft's [Embedded Learning Library](https://microsoft.github.io/ELL) or [Edge ML Library](https://github.com/Microsoft/EdgeML).

For ARM devices you should also look into [CMSIS-NN library](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/tree/develop/CMSIS/NN) and even more specifically into [X-CUBE-AI extension pack](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/x-cube-ai.html) if you're using an stm32 device.